# Sorting by Multliple columns

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have an xPage with a repeater linked to a view with 30 columns in the view.  I have two combo boxes where the user selects the 1st level sort and then the 2nd Level sort column.  So I need to sort by two columns.  I can get the Primary Sort by setting the SortColumn value to what column name selected in the first combo box, but can't figure out how to do two levels of sorting.

Comment: I think it is not possible with Notes/Domino (within borders of good performance and simple design). Try DOJO grid or DomSql instead.

Answer (score 0):

We might be able to do this with Ext-js. We are currently running version 4.1.1 not sure if it works in that version, but 4.2.2 seems to hace this functionality.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/example/grid/multiple-sorting.html

Send me an IM.

Answer (score 0):

One possible simple but not recommended if you need to apply sort on too many columns.

Create a separate view with each column as primary and the other column as secondary along with a XPage design element for each view. Redirect the page to corresponding XPage on the combo box selection.

If there are 5 columns that need to be sorted then 25 views and 25 XPage design elements are required. if there are 10 columns then 100 views and 100 XPage design elements.